# one month rails pinterest clone adding omniauth Facebook authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I have setup a pinterest website clone from onemonth.com tutorials. However, I found another tutorial on adding omniauth Facebook authentication to devise.

I can login, but when i try to access the add pin function it produces an error.

https://github.com/hcharrington/rememberch

```
NoMethodError in PinsController#new
undefined method `pins' for #<User:0x007fc3fc7e0ac8>

 Extracted source (around line #20):

  def new
   @pin = current_user.pins.build 
  end
```

Comment: Does it only happen when you sign up with Facebook?

Comment: no. it happens with regular devise setup. not just omniauth.

Comment: I checked out your project it works fine for me. Have you tried restarting your server?